How to estimate the confidence interval of a very small proportion?
I want to the estimate the confidence interval of a very small proportion. Let's say I have simple random sample of 1000 and 4 people answered the question with yes. One might want to make use of the normality assumption and calculate the confidence interval with the basic formula
$$
CI ± z * \sqrt{p^ * (1-p)/n)}
$$
However, for this to hold one usually imposes the restriction that $n * p ≥ 5$ and $n * (1-p) ≥ 5$, which is violated in this case.
Hence, my question: If I want to say: "With 95% confindence, the share of people answering yes is smaller than x%". How do I find $x$?

i would suggest the jeffreys interval
see here for this and alternatives
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval
jeffreys interval is a simple formula that just uses the beta distribution (available even in excel)

I think this is precisely what Beta distribution is for.
If $r\sim Beta\left(\alpha,\,\beta\right)$ then $r$ is the rate of success given that you have observed $\alpha-1$ successes and $\beta-1$ failures (with flat prior, i.e. no other assumptions). So simply extract the percentile interval from it.
In Python I would write:
import scipy.stats as sp_st

yes_count=4
people_count=1000
sp_st.beta(yes_count+1, people_count-yes_count+1).ppf([0.025, 0.975])
>>> array([0.00162379, 0.0101995])

To get the 90% credible interval for the rate of yes-answers
